# Try/Except entire block without breaking flow

Tags: python-3.x, try-except

I have some code like this:

```
var_1 = something_complicated("Look here")[0].text.split()[0]
var_2 = something_complicated("Look there")[0].text.split()[2:]
var_3 = something_complicated("Look up")[0].text.split()
var_4 = " ".join(something_complicated("Look down"))
var_5 = int(something_complicated("Don't Look here").split()[1])
```

Except more like 15 variables. I want to write something that will have this effect:

```
try:
    var_1 = something_complicated("Look here")[0].text.split()[0]
    var_2 = something_complicated("Look there")[0].text.split()[2:]
    var_3 = something_complicated("Look up")[0].text.split()
    var_4 = " ".join(something_complicated("Look down"))
    var_5 = int(something_complicated("Don't Look here").split()[1])
except IndexError, TypeError:
    var_that_caused_error = ""
```

And the program doesn't quit, even if the error happens in var_1, the rest of the variables still get populated

The solution i can think of right now is try/excepting each line, but that seems like a nightmare, and also doesn't follow DRY. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can write code to check for the conditions that raise those exceptions and if it's repetitive, you can factor it out to a function or functions.

Comment: @DennisSparrow, could you please show a short example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach, though there's probably a better way to go about this.

```
try:
     something_complicated("Look here")[0].text.split()[0]
     something_complicated("Look there")[0].text.split()[2:]
     something_complicated("Look up")[0].text.split()
     " ".join(something_complicated("Look down"))
     int(something_complicated("Don't Look here").split()[1])
     var1 = something_complicated("Look here")[0].text.split()[0]
     var2 = something_complicated("Look there")[0].text.split()[2:]
     var3 = something_complicated("Look up")[0].text.split()
     var4 = " ".join(something_complicated("Look down"))
     var5 = int(something_complicated("Don't Look here").split()[1])

except:
    var_that_caused_error = ""
```

Comment: Thanks for giving it a try man. Don't all the exp's run when the program is initiated? There's nothing done to them, so the program can still break.

Comment: @Lafftar Yep you're right. I fixed the program, I think this should work.

Comment: Okay, so you're running the functions without saving the return data into anything, 5 times, before returning them to a variable, 5 times. If an error happens on the second line, won't the entire program still fail? Also, how does this program know what var caused the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is useful enough to be an answer, but you asked for an example and code posted in comments is size-limited and hard to read, so I am posting this answer in the hope that it may be useful.

Exceptions are supposed to disrupt control flow.  If you don't want the control flow disruption, you can, as you said, put each statement in its own `try` clause, or you can check for error conditions and avoid doing the thing that would raise an exception.  For example, before you try to use an element of a sequence, you can check whether the element exists.

Example:

```
#var_1 = something_complicated("Look here")[0].text.split()[0]

var_1 = ""                          #   Default value until we know success
var = something_complicated("Look here")
if len(var) > 0:                    #   Prevent IndexError
    var = var[0]
    if hasattr(var, "text"):        #   Prevent AttributeError
        var = var.text
        if isinstance(var, str):    #   Prevent AttributeError
            var = var.split()
            if len(var) > 0:        #   Prevent IndexError
                var_1 = var[0]      #   Success
```

I know this is a lot more lines.  That's the price you pay for keeping your control flow under control.  You don't necessarily have to check for every possible error condition.  You can skip checking for conditions that you are sufficiently confident will not come up, as long as you are willing to live with an exception if one does come up.

As an example of factoring to a function, say you see the pattern `[0].text.split()` recurring as in your sample code.  You can make a function to do that and check for error conditions like this:

```
def text_words(obj):
    if len(obj) > 0:                    #   Prevent IndexError
        result = obj[0]
        if hasattr(result, "text"):     #   Prevent AttributeError
            result = result.text
            if isinstance(result, str): #   Prevent AttributeError
                return result.split()
    return None
    
words = text_words(something_complicated("Look here"))
var_1 = words[0] if words else ""
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer these Dennis, I really appreciate it. I think I understand what you're saying, the issue is, as you said, this solution is more work than just try/excepting each line. Also, I would have to write different text_words() because they all have different transformations. It's like a 10x increase in effort. Regardless, I appreciate you spending the time to write a detailed response, thank you.